# How can I hide the toolbar in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, toolbar

I never use the toolbar in Notepad++. Is there any way I can hide it?

I'm talking about this part:

[image]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Click on Settings Menu -> Preferences -> General tab and ensure that the Hide toolbar checkbox is checked

[image]

Comment: Awfully, painfully obvious answer! :]

Comment: you can customize tool bar by adding plugin named "Customize Toolbar"; To install Customize Toolbar, open Plugin Manager from Plugins—> Plugin Manager—> Show Plugin Manager. Under the Available tab, select Customize Toolbar and click Install. (for more : http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/customize-toolbar-notepad-plugin-to-add-and-delete-custom-buttons/)

Comment: There is one more way to hide only selected tools from toolbar. http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/customize-toolbar-notepad-plugin-to-add-and-delete-custom-buttons/